# Export XML in SQL Server to a text file as well as XML results to XML

Tags: sql, xml, integration

I have a XML result set that I need to export as a text file. This is a control file that will be picked up by a Web Service.

I have read through various posts and the Unable to cast TEXT to XML in SQL Server is the closest post I can find to what I am trying to achieve.

Please keep in mind I am very new to SQL. So take it easy with the salt. You fine folks can be brutal!

I just know this can be done and this would save me so much time in integrating two systems. I would like to know how I can get these results to drop to BOTH an XML and a text file.

Here is my Code.

```
USE [Development]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].      [INTEGRATION_MASTER_TABLE_XML_CONTROL_FILE]
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[INTEGRATION_MASTER_TABLE_XML_CONTROL_FILE]
AS
declare
@xml nvarchar(max),
@ControlVars nvarchar(max)
set @xml =
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'
+ N'' + CHAR(10);
select  @ControlVars =
CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
(
(select
'<Import id="'+ IMPORT_ID +'" ',
'company="'+ COMPANY_ID +'" ',
'userName="'+ USER_NAME +'" ',
'description="'+ DESCRIPTION +'" ',
'writeLogFile="'+ WRITE_LOG_FILE +'" ',
'fileName="'+ FILE_NAME +'" ',
'errorToEmailAddress="'+ ERROR_TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS +'" '
from TABLE_CONTROL_FILE
where 1=1
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')))
set @xml = @xml + @ControlVars +'/>'
select @xml;
```

Thank you kindly!
Pennie

I don't understand what you are asking for with regard to input as I am just pulling values from my table. The output is returning this xml to one column when I execute the SP.

I would like to execute the sp and save these results as a .txt file to a file location. I would also like to execute the sp and save these results as an .xml file to a file location. 
Thanks. P

Thanks Kamran. I don't know what to use to extract the file. I started with a job and that did not work for me. There are a lot of options. Maybe if I explain the business need you can help me nail down the best avenue.

I need to automate running this SP every 15 minutes (I am assuming a scheduled job is what I need) and drop the results as a .txt file and an .xml file to a dir on the server to be picked up by a Web Service.

Thanks. 
Pennie

More to this. I tested xp_cmdshell and received the following error.

Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure.

Obviously this is not going to be an option for me. I can probably make the case to enable this but before I do, is there another way?

If there a security risk associated with xp_cmdshell being enabled, I'm fairly sure my admin will not enable it. There must be another way.

Pennie

I have been trying to understand this most of this day. I enabled xp_cmdshell on my local SQL Server.

I'm now getting this result.

[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLTpK.gif) 
Here is my code.

```
USE [Development_Local]
GO
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[MASTER_TABLE_XML_CONTROL_FILE_2]         
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MASTER_TABLE_XML_CONTROL_FILE_2]
AS
declare

@xml nvarchar(max),
@ControlVars nvarchar(max)

set @xml =
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>'
+ N'' + CHAR(10);

select @ControlVars =
CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
(
(select
'<Import id="'+ IMPORT_ID +'" ',
'company="'+ COMPANY_ID +'" ',
'userName="'+ USER_NAME +'" ',
'description="'+ DESCRIPTION +'" ',
'writeLogFile="'+ WRITE_LOG_FILE +'" ',
'fileName="'+ FILE_NAME +'" ',
'errorToEmailAddress="'+ ERROR_TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS +'" '

from MASTER_TABLE_XML_CONTROL_FILE
where 1=1

FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')))

set @xml = @xml + @ControlVars +'/>'

select @xml;
CREATE TABLE MyXMLTable
(
xCol XML
) ;

INSERT INTO MyXMLTable ( xCol )
SELECT
@xml

DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Filename VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @Filename = 'C:\Client XML\Test.xml'
SELECT @Command = 'bcp "select xCol from ' + DB_NAME()
+ '..MyXMLTable" queryout '
+ @Filename + ' -w -T -S' + @@servername
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @command

SELECT CONVERT(nVARCHAR(max),BulkColumn)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Client XML\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
DROP TABLE MyXMLTable
```

Okay I figured it out. Apparently I cannot have spaces in the DIR for output. Oh my.

I would still be interested in knowing if there is another way to do this w/o xp_cmdshell. I seriously doubt my admin will enable this for me. It seems to be a security risk.

Comment: Can you show an example of your input and expected output for one row of data?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for with regard to input as I am just pulling values from my table. The output is returning this xml to one column when I execute the SP. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Import id="47" company="84" userName="FileImport" description="Client_Intl" writeLogFile="True" fileName="import_client.dat" errorToEmailAddress="p@me.com" /> I would like to execute the sp and save these results as a .txt file to a file location. I would also like to execute the sp and save these results as an .xml file to a file location.

Comment: How are you intending to extract to file? Via xp_cmdshell and bcp or another method?

Comment: If you can't use `xp_cmdshell` (due to security restrictions), do it using PowerShell (that is outside the context of SQL Server). There are also Ole Automation procedures but they're clunky to say they least (plus also require allowing access to those procedures). If you need to stay within the context of SQL Server, `xp_cmdshell` + `BCP` is is the only practical way.

Comment: For one of our customers I realised a different approach: Within SQL Server you define a Tabel Valued Function returning your data. This TVF you then call from an external application to get your data as a one-line-call. This external app can be a tiny self written tool, or Excel, or [ ... many ...] The biggest advantage was, that you can write the file in the context oft the caller. Otherwise you are restricted to the file destinations your SQL Server is allowed to write to...